# How to get auto refreshing time in php

Tags: php

This php time function shows fixed time. I mean to say when page refreshes, time gets updated.

```
$time = date("H:i:s");
```

Is there any possibility to get current time (auto refreshing current time)?

I mean to say that time will be updated every second.

In that case how to set code for

```
$time = ?
```

Comment: Learn about javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript for this. Here's an example:

```
<?php

echo "
    <div id='current-time'></div>
    <script>
      setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById('current-time').innerHTML = new Date().toTimeString();
      }, 1000);
    </script>
";
```

Here's the js snippet:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById('current-time').innerHTML = new Date().toTimeString();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="current-time"></div>
```